# Creating and populating custom list skins with C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, custom-controls

Consider use case of custom list element, that has multiple rows and other other data elements, like pictures. So if I have a list of data instances, how do I use the data source to populate custom list. I also want to bind the list to the display element.

### Sample class

```
public class BeerData
{
    public string imageUrl { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string brewery { get; set; }
    public string beer { get; set; }
    public double reiting { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

### Personal effort

At the moment, I'm using datagridview

```
private BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
// ...

bs.DataSource = typeof(BeerData);
foreach (BeerData entry in new BeerData[]{ new BeerData()
{
    reiting = 4.2,
    name = "Bell's Hopslam Ale",
    brewery = "Bell's Brewery, Inc",
    beer = "Imperiial IPA",
    image = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/" +
    "commons/6/60/Kriek_Beer_1.jpg"
}/* , ... */})
    bs.Add(entry);

grid.DataSource = bs;
grid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

lName.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", bs, "name"));
lImage.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("ImageLocation", bs, "image"));
// ...
```

### Personal effort 2

```
public static class BeerLoader
{
    public static List<BeerData> result = new List<BeerData>();
    static BeerLoader() {
        add1BogusDataInstance();
    }
    public static void add1BogusDataInstance()
    {
        foreach (BeerData entry in new BeerData[]{ new BeerData()
        {
            reiting = 4.2,
            name = "Bell's Hopslam Ale",
            brewery = "Bell's Brewery, Inc",
            beer = "Imperiial IPA",
            imageUrl = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/" + 
            "commons/6/60/Kriek_Beer_1.jpg"
        }})
            result.Add(entry);
    }
    public static List<BeerData> LoadData()
    {
        return result;
    }
}
```

### Sample of desired result

Example of list part that would replace datagridview

[image: image of desired output]

Image [source](http://blog.digitalbackcountry.com/2011/01/creating-custom-list-skins-for-the-blackberry-playbook/)

### Question

I assume, that I need to create a `user control` and then create list of that user control or something equivalent. Could not find a winform example using google, so I want to know how this is done.

Comment: All you have to do is...hmm, beer...what was the question?

Comment: does it need to be winforms? This would be far easier with WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if I would use wpf DataTemplate of:

```
<Border HorizontalAlignment="Left" BorderThickness="2" Margin="3" 
    Padding="2" CornerRadius="2" BorderBrush="Black" >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <Border HorizontalAlignment="Left" BorderThickness="1" Margin="3"
            CornerRadius="1" BorderBrush="Gray" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Image  Width="128" 
                Source="{Binding Path=imageUrl}" ></Image>
        </Border>
        <StackPanel Width="120">
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=name}"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=brewery}"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=beer}"/>
            <StackPanel Width="120" Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <Label Content="AVG Rating: "/>
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=reiting}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

with a static data provider and gui:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <ObjectDataProvider 
        ObjectType="{x:Type local:BeerLoader}" MethodName="LoadData" />
</Window.DataContext>

<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Add" Click="Button_Click" />
    <ListBox Name="data" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
</StackPanel>
```

I can get:

[image: example]

what is a lot better and clearer.

<s>However data is not static and I have not found a workaround yet.</s>

In the C# code, I just need to change collection from `List` to `ObservableCollection`.

Answer (score 2):

The way you are displaying your "list", makes me think you might try to use a ListBox instead, with the DrawMode = OwnerDrawFixed and an ItemHeight = 64 (or whatever).  Then in the DrawItem event for the ListBox, you can draw your output as needed.

If you need to use the DataGridView, then I would look into the CellPaint event and sort of do the same thing.